# Beginner: struggle with PBR textures

Tags: texturing, pbr

I have downloaded a metal foil PBR tried to apply it to a model I created with node wrangler. As you can see in the screenshot, it appears different than the material preview.

I have added a HDRI, tried Eevee and Cycles, looks the same. The node set up looks correct. The material preview looks fine (see picture).

The texture I downloaded is this one: https://www.texturecan.com/details/25/

I must be missing very basic something but what? I encounter this issue with all the PBR textures I try. [image]

Comment: Can you show us the UV Map of your object please? I think there could be an issue with the UV, depending on what you have mapped from the texture coordinate node

Comment: I just realised I hadn't UV unwrapped the object before applying the texture... So now I did and it works perfectly fine. Sorry for this and many thanks for your help @B.Pader